# How to use Bourne shell as the active Ruby shell under Windows

Tags: ruby, environment-variables, sh

**Summary**: On a Windows machine, how can I make it so that the Bourne shell is the active Ruby shell? Here's what I'd like to happen:

```
irb> exec('echo $SHELL')
/bin/sh
```

The actual output is:

```
irb> exec('echo $SHELL')
$SHELL
```

Which is what happens if I try to run the command manually in `cmd.exe`. According to the Ruby docs, it looks like the `exec` call checks `$RUBYSHELL` and `$COMSPEC` (in that order?). I've tried setting `$RUBYSHELL` to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe"` where I have a copy of `sh`, `/bin/sh`, and `/sh`, none of which appear to work. It looks like it basically ignores `RUBYSHELL` completely...

**Why?**: I'm using a Ruby gem which makes a call to `exec` and passes it the result of `Shellwords.shelljoin`. That call escapes characters, but only for the Bourne shell. When run under Windows' `cmd.exe`, it seems to barf on any escaped quote characters and just ignore them instead. As a result, the command is not interpreted correctly. I guess another way to solve my problem would be to let me know if there's a better cross-platform way to execute an escape command sequence, but it seems to me like my problem would be solved if I could make `sh` my active Ruby shell.

Comment: Have you tried setting the windows native environment variables `RUBYSHELL` and/or `COMSPEC` (i.e. not the git `sh` variables)? I'm pretty sure ruby/irb on windows has no mingw bindings, which means it will be reading the windows native environment and not the mingw environment.

Comment: @Casper Yep, that's how I'm doing it. I'm just going through the control panel and setting `RUBYSHELL` equal to whatever I want. They appear to show up properly when I run `env` in either `cmd.exe` or `sh.exe`.

Comment: Have you considered overriding the method that's causing you problems. A small change to change the way characters are escaped to be more Windows friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I would execute the shell directly, e.g.  `exec('c:\bin\sh')`

I should note (you probably know this), that windows environment variables are accessed by surrounding them with percentage signs:

```
irb> exec(`echo %SHELL%`)
```

Comment: Yep -- I knew about the percent signs in Windows. The hope was that the test would show that it was working properly in `sh` because the command would actually print out the location properly, rather than the Windows output which just looked like `$SHELL` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec("sh","-c","echo $SHELL")
```

This pragmatic approach should be able to solve the case, in my environment it works the same in different runtime environments, for example:

mingw32 on Windows 7 64bit 
ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [i386-mingw32]
[image: ruby 2.1.6p336]

OS-X 10.10.3
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]
[image: ruby 2.0.0p451]